# Error 503 Service Unavailable Varnish

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, varnish

So I setup a new cloud based instance with Ubuntu 12.04, with nginx, php5-fpm and varnish.

Before I installed and configured Varnish, the website worked fine, virtual hosts worked.  After setting up varnish I'm getting Error 503 Service Unavailable now.

My nginx conf looks like this:

```
server {
   listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080;
   server_name example.com ;
   root /var/www/example.com/public_html;
   if ($http_host != "example.com") {
             rewrite ^ http://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
   }
   index index.php index.html;
   location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
   }
   location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
   }
   # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac).
   location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
   }
   location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }
   # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
   rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
   location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
   }
   location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }

    #Roots theme clean URL rewrites
    location ~ ^/assets/(img|js|css)/(.*)$ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /wp-content/themes/sitename/assets/$1/$2;
    }
    location ~ ^/plugins/(.*)$ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /wp-content/plugins/$1;
    }

}
```

/etc/default/varnish looks like the this:

```
# Configuration file for varnish
#
# /etc/init.d/varnish expects the variables $DAEMON_OPTS, $NFILES and $MEMLOCK
# to be set from this shell script fragment.
#
# Note: If systemd is installed, this file is obsolete and ignored.  You will
# need to copy /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service to /etc/systemd/system/ and
# edit that file.

# Should we start varnishd at boot?  Set to "no" to disable.
START=yes

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
NFILES=131072

# Maximum locked memory size (for ulimit -l)
# Used for locking the shared memory log in memory.  If you increase log size,
# you need to increase this number as well
MEMLOCK=82000

# Default varnish instance name is the local nodename.  Can be overridden with
# the -n switch, to have more instances on a single server.
# INSTANCE=$(uname -n)

# This file contains 4 alternatives, please use only one.

## Alternative 1, Minimal configuration, no VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# content server on localhost:8080.  Use a 1GB fixed-size cache file.
#
# DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
#              -T localhost:6082 \
#            -b localhost:8080 \
#            -u varnish -g varnish \
#            -S /etc/varnish/secret \
#            -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,1G"


## Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.  Use a 1GB
# fixed-size cache file.
#
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

/etc/varnish/default.vcl looks like the following:

```
 backend default {
.host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
.port = "8080";    }
```

Checking varnishlog I see this:

```
11 SessionOpen  c xx.xxx.xxx.xxx 4712 :80
11 ReqStart     c xx.xxx.xxx.xxx 4712 1475226459
11 RxRequest    c GET
11 RxURL        c /
11 RxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
11 RxHeader     c Host: example.com
11 RxHeader     c Connection: keep-alive
11 RxHeader     c Cache-Control: max-age=0
11 RxHeader     c Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
11 RxHeader     c User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.155 Safari/537.22
11 RxHeader     c Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
11 RxHeader     c Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
11 RxHeader     c Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
11 RxHeader     c Cookie: __utma=148547044.766489551.1362139914.1362151355.1362156101.3; __utmz=148547044.1362139914.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __cfduid=d92c50421d4bba63041d6d12ba960d3151362551863; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_lo
11 VCL_call     c recv lookup
11 VCL_call     c hash
11 Hash         c /
11 Hash         c example.com
11 VCL_return   c hash
11 VCL_call     c miss fetch
11 FetchError   c no backend connection
11 VCL_call     c error deliver
11 VCL_call     c deliver deliver
11 TxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
11 TxStatus     c 503
11 TxResponse   c Service Unavailable
11 TxHeader     c Server: Varnish
11 TxHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
11 TxHeader     c Retry-After: 5
11 TxHeader     c Content-Length: 419
11 TxHeader     c Accept-Ranges: bytes
11 TxHeader     c Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2013 20:14:13 GMT
11 TxHeader     c X-Varnish: 1475226459
11 TxHeader     c Age: 0
11 TxHeader     c Via: 1.1 varnish
11 TxHeader     c Connection: close
11 Length       c 419
11 ReqEnd       c 1475226459 1362600853.513662100 1362600853.513980627 0.000180006 0.000249863 0.000068665
11 SessionClose c error
11 StatSess     c 70.194.150.230 4712 0 1 1 0 0 0 257 419
11 SessionOpen  c 70.194.150.230 4713 :80
11 ReqStart     c 70.194.150.230 4713 1475226460
11 RxRequest    c GET
11 RxURL        c /favicon.ico
11 RxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
11 RxHeader     c Host: example.com
11 RxHeader     c Connection: keep-alive
11 RxHeader     c Accept: */*
11 RxHeader     c User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.155 Safari/537.22
11 RxHeader     c Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
11 RxHeader     c Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
11 RxHeader     c Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
11 VCL_call     c recv lookup
11 VCL_call     c hash
11 Hash         c /favicon.ico
11 Hash         c example.com
11 VCL_return   c hash
11 VCL_call     c miss fetch
11 FetchError   c no backend connection
11 VCL_call     c error deliver
11 VCL_call     c deliver deliver
11 TxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
11 TxStatus     c 503
11 TxResponse   c Service Unavailable
11 TxHeader     c Server: Varnish
11 TxHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
11 TxHeader     c Retry-After: 5
11 TxHeader     c Content-Length: 419
11 TxHeader     c Accept-Ranges: bytes
11 TxHeader     c Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2013 20:14:13 GMT
11 TxHeader     c X-Varnish: 1475226460
11 TxHeader     c Age: 0
11 TxHeader     c Via: 1.1 varnish
11 TxHeader     c Connection: close
11 Length       c 419
11 ReqEnd       c 1475226460 1362600853.751207590 1362600853.751491070 0.000154257 0.000221491 0.000061989
11 SessionClose c error
11 StatSess     c 70.194.150.230 4713 0 1 1 0 0 0 257 419
```

Comment: Can you please paste complete `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` file here. I believe what you pasted is not the complete file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like varnish can't connect to your nginx backend - are you able to connect to it by visiting http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 ?